# Save ActionResult file to server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a *method* that returns an ActionResult that returns a text file to the browser.  I would like to call it from another controller in the project and save the file to the server.  How can I do this?  Thanks

Added examples of unsuccessful attempts in edit.

Example:

```
public ActionResult ReportX()
{
// stuff
return ExportGridView("my name", vModel.ReportParameters, vModel.Records, "", "other name");
}

attempt:
Controllers.SampleController bdc = new Controllers.SampleController();

FileStreamResult res = new FileStreamResult(bdc.ReportX(),"");
res = (FileStreamResult)bdc.ReportX();

attempt:
Controllers.SampleController bdc = new Controllers.SampleController();
FileStreamResult res = (FileStreamResult)bdc.ReportX();
```

more code:

```
   public ActionResult ExportGridView(string exportType, ReportParameters reportParams, object data, string excludedColumns = "", string fileNameReplacement = "")
            {
    //stuff

                        result = (System.Web.Mvc.FileResult)GridViewExtension.ExportToCsv(gvs, data, fileName, true, csvOpt);


                        return result;
                }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to show you have attempted this yourself first.

Comment: Why do it like this? Why not share the mechanics of file generation between the two actions by means of a shared method/service, and in one case return to the user, in the other case, stream to disk?

Comment: What exactly does "ExportGridView" do? It's some custom function of yours which returns a FileResult I guess? Can you show us?

Comment: `I have an ActionResult that returns a text file to the browser.`  More accurately, you have a *method* that returns an `ActionResult` representing a text file.

Comment: Ok so instead of calling the ReportX or ExportGridView methods, your other method could surely just call GridViewExtension.ExportToCsv with the relevant parameters. Then you cut out all of the unnecessary HTTP-related abstraction added by the conversion to a FileResult etc.

Comment: @ADyson ExportGridView does some formatting of the data before returning it to the _calling method_ that returns the ActionResult to the browser.  ReportX is in another controller and I am calling that since it has the infrastructure to get the necessary data for the file.

Comment: " ExportGridView does some formatting of the data"...no it doesn't, it just casts the result of GridViewExtension.ExportToCsv as a FileResult. That's not formatting of data, it's just casting an object.

Comment: "ReportX is in another controller and I am calling that since it has the infrastructure to get the necessary data"...you mean it can supply the necessary parameter values to the Export method? Where does it get those values from? What's stopping your other controller from getting hold of those values? It sounds like need some shared functionality which both controllers can make use of. What you're trying to do (calling one action method from another) won't work well and also creates an unnecessary and less-than-obvious dependency between two otherwise unrelated pieces of code

Comment: @ADyson The "//stuff" part of the code in ExportGridview is about 300 lines.  I am trying to not have dependencies which is the reason I am trying to call the existing code to just get the file and download it on the server.  It apparently is not the way to do it since I am not finding a solution.

Comment: " I am trying to not have dependencies"...then don't call one controller action from another, that's a really crazy dependency.

Comment: "The "//stuff" part of the code in ExportGridview is about 300 lines"...in that case, make ExportGridView just return the result of  ExportToCSV directly (what type of object does it return, by the way?), so you can call it from other places without the extra HTTP overhead, and put the casting into a FileResult bit into the ReportX method, since that's the only place where you need it. Then you've got a re-usable multi-purpose method for producing a CSV file, which doesn't contain any functionality relating to downloading it - that kind of stuff belongs in the controller

Answer (score 0):

The DevExpress ExportToCsv *method* returns an actionresult. I didn't want to try to reformat the data in some other way.  The custom format is already done in our wrapper.  The problem was that I needed to have a partial view for the export grid to work. I did not realize that since I was calling the ReportX **method** from another controller I needed to make another wrapper function to get the correct partial view so that the DevExpress magic could work.  Thanks for your help @ADyson